# Compressing json content in yaml file

Tags: json, yaml, compression

In one of our configurations, we are using json content inside the yaml file for managing kubernetes application. Got a requirement to compress the content of json file. Aware if its a separate json file can do compression using for ex; cat example.json |gzip |base 64".

```
more configmap.yaml 
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: app-dashboard

data:
  app-dashboard.json: |-
        {
          "annotations": {
            "list": [
              {
                "builtIn": 1,
                "datasource": {
                  "type": "datasource",
```

But the requirement is to compress the above json content inside yaml file which has to be called in other main configuration yaml file